# Committed PNG files to Git on Windows broke %PNG\r\n header

Tags: windows, git, png, newline

I added lots of PNG files to a Git repository on Windows, unfortunately with the setting `text eol=lf` to not commit Windows line breaks.

The problem is that the PNG header *must* be in the form `%PNG\r\n` and now all PNG images are in Git with the header `%PNG\n` and cannot be displayed like that.

I tried adding this line to `.gitattributes`:

```
*.png binary
```

But the files, although correct in the working directory, still show up as unchanged and `git add` does nothing.

I managed to fix single files with checking out the broken version and editing it manually but I hope there is a less tedious way.

How can I fix my repository without modifying the individual files?

Comment: "problem is that the PNG header must be in the form %PNG\r\n"  Incidentally: The header was designed in that way precisely to detect that the newlines were messed up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I managed to solve it myself while writing down the question:

1. Remove all PNG files from repository but keep the working copies:

   ```
   git rm --cached **/*.png
   ```
2. Add them again

   ```
   git add **/*.png
   ```
3. Ready to commit!